# Sefer Yereim divided into 613 mitzvos

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, mitzvah

The **Sefer Yereim** by [**Rav Eliezer MiMitz**](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Rabbi_Eliezer_MiMitz) is an important work on *halacha*. It's also a list of the 613 *mitzvos*, as that is how he organized this *halachic* work. What many do not know is he based his list on the one of the **Bahag**, with some differences (parenthetically, I noticed he lived at the same time as the Rambam. Maybe he didn't have the latter's Sefer HaMitzvos, and the Bahag's list was all he had to work with, rather than making his own).

If one were to [look at the work](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim?lang=he), they'll notice that there are only 464 sections, not 613. The author himself addresses this in his [introduction](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim%2C_Author%27s_Introduction?lang=he) and says that  sometimes he grouped together mitzvos that were related.

> כי כל מצוות הנכללות בדמיון אחד אייחד לבד בכלל אחד.‏

He's more explicit at [the end](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim.464.3?with=all&lang=he) of his work:

> וסיימתי מצות ותולדותיהן כאשר השגתי בעצת דעתי והשבתים כאשר מצאתים בספר רב יהודאי גאון ז"ל וכללתים בארבע מאות ששים וארבעה כי בכמה מקומות כללתי שתים כאחת.‏

I was wondering if anyone took the time to go through his *sefer* and indicate how many *mitzvos* are covered in each section. It would be nice to know if it actually came to 613, and to know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between 1892 and 1902, R. Avraham Abba Schiff of Minsk printed from manuscript a complete edition of Sefer Yere'im. (Before then, printed editions were based on the abridged version produced by R. Binyamin b. R. Avraham HaRofe.)

In one of the introductions to his work, R. Schiff appended a treatise called Bereichot BeCheshbon, suggesting a full list of the 613 *mitzvot* according to Yere'im.

It can be found [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1607260501740&pagenum=40&book=154489) in this edition at Otzar HaChochmah (no subscription needed), and [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_Yereim.45.28?lang=he) at sefaria.org (where it seems to have mistakenly been included within the text of the Yere'im itself).

Comment: Thank you. I missed this because it's missing in the Hebrew books version. In the original it was part of the introduction to part two. On Hebrew books the first several pages are missing.