# How many lists of the 613 Mitzvot are there, and who wrote them?

Tags: mitzvah

How many different individuals listed the 613 Mitzvot? Who was the first, and who was the most recent?

Comment: @robev - this is your specialty

Comment: Do we count all the Azharot?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Section 1 – The first to count the Taryag

##### 1)  [Bahag – Ba’al Halachos Gedolos](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14119&st=&pgnum=6) (identity disputed, 8th century Babylonia)

**Life**: Most<sup>1</sup> say Halachos Gedolos was written by [**Rav Shimon Kaira**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90) in the year 741 CE. Others<sup>2</sup> say it was written by [**Rav Yehudai Gaon**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99_%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F)<sup>3</sup>. Both lived in the 8th century.

**Style**: His list is really just an introduction to a work on *halacha*. He lists all of his *mitzvos* by name, originally without any punctuation. The names are usually just a quotation of the verse they’re from. As such, it’s hard to determine when one *mitzvah* starts and when one stops. He doesn’t number them, and one could easily find a different number other than 613 *mitzvos* in his list. As such, later authorities struggled to divide up his list into 613. They often had to emend the text, or interpret one *mitzvah* to be really multiple in one, or the vice versa.

**Unique Characteristics**: Besides being the first to enumerate the *mitzvos*, he doesn’t hesitate including *DeRabbanans* in the list. He divides the *mitzvos* into 7 categories, instead of the better-known division of 248 positive and 365 negative *mitzvos*. Instead he lists 71 “*Onshim*” (ordered from most severe to least severe), 277 negative *mitzvos* for the individual, 200 positive mitzvos for the individual, and 65 “*Parshiyos*”. This latter category is a mix of 48 positive and 17 negative *mitzvos*, understood to be incumbent upon the community instead of the individual.

### Section 2 – The Azharos (Taryag composed into a poem)

##### 2) [Rav Sa’adiah Gaon](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=10515) ([c. 892 – 942 CE, Babylonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon))

**Life**: He became the Gaon, or Rosh Yeshiva, of the Yeshiva in Sura, Babylonia, at the age of 36. He wrote a translation of the Torah into Arabic. His most famous work is most likely Emunos V’Deos, a philosophical work originally written in Arabic.

**Unique Characteristics**: He wrote two *piyutim*: one according to the division of the **Bahag** (although with a different order), and one organizing the *mitzvos* according the Ten Commandments. This latter *piyut* is referenced by **Rashi**<sup>4</sup>. The two versions differ in the exact listing of the *Taryag*. Both are featured in Rav Sa’adiah Gaon’s *Siddur*. He doesn’t list dozens of mitzvos which everyone else counted (for example: *Bal Tosif* and *Bal Tigra*<sup>5</sup>, *Ahavas Hashem*, *Kiddush Hashem*<sup>6</sup>).

##### 3) Ata Hinchalta (identity disputed)

**Life**: Some<sup>7</sup> say this *piyut* was written by **Rav Eliyahu HaZaken** (see below). Others<sup>8</sup> say it was written by [**Rabbeinu Shimon HaGadol**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7) (c. 950 – 1020 CE, France). Others<sup>9</sup> even date this work to the times of **Rav Sa’adiah Gaon**, or even earlier.

**Style**: A poem written as an alphabetical acrostic, sometimes going forwards, sometimes backwards. There isn’t a clear order to the mitzvos, and the main commentary on it expresses an inability to discern the order.

##### 4) [Rav Eliyahu HaZaken](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=145067) ([c. 980 – 1060 CE, France](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%94%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%9F))

**Life**: He was **Rav Hai Gaon**’s brother-in-law. He lived in France and was a student of **Rabbeinu Gershom**. His *Azharos* are cited by **Tosafos** in a few places<sup>10</sup>.

**Style**: It’s a poem written mostly as an alphabetical acrostic which goes forwards and backwards. Like the **Bahag**, he divided the *mitzvos* into unique categories. First the *mitzvos aseh*, then *parshiyos*, then *onshim*, then *mitzvos lo sa’aseh*.

##### 5) [Rav Shlomo ibn Gabirol](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42063&st=&pgnum=94) ([c. 1021 – 1070 CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ibn_Gabirol))

**Life**: He was a very popular *paytan* or poet, and some of our Shabbos *zemiros* were written by him. Some say<sup>11</sup> he composed the popular song “*Anim Zemiros*”, and others say<sup>12</sup> he wrote “*Adon Olam*”. He was also a philosopher. By the age of 25 he had written many poems and a few works on character development.

**Style**: Each stanza is written in the same way, with the first three parts sharing a rhyming scheme, with the last part always ending in –im. Each stanza usually includes one or many *mitzvos*, depending on the interpretation of the commentator.

**Unique Characteristics**: Unlike the other *Azharos*, he divides his *piyut* into 248 positive *mitzvos* and 365 negative *mitzvos*, like the Rambam would later do.

##### 6) [Rav Yitzchak ben Reuven Albargaloni](https://hebrewbooks.org/42063) ([1043 – ? CE](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99))

**Life**: Lived in the same generation as the **Rif**. Albargaloni just means from Barcelona, or in Hebrew HaBartzaloni. He should not be confused with **Rav Yehuda HaBartzaloni** (12th century). Both have been referred to as Ri HaBartzaloni. He was an ancestor to **Ramban** (see below). He was the one who translated **Rav Hai Gaon**’s important work on business *halacha* “*HaMekach VeHamemkar*” from Arabic into Hebrew.

**Style**: An alphabetical acrostic where each stanza has four lines where the first three start with the same letter. All four lines share the same rhyming scheme, and the last line is a verse in Tanach. Like **Rav Eliyahu HaZaken** (see above), first he lists 200 positive *mitzvos*, 65 *parshiyos*, 71 *onshim*, then 277 negative *mitzvos*.

---

##### 7) [Sefer Yereim](https://hebrewbooks.org/14049) – [Rav Eliezer MiMitz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A5) (1140 – 1237 CE)

**Life**: He was one of the Ba’alei HaTosafos, often quoted by **Tosafos** and other Ashkenazi *poskim*. He was a student of **Rabbeinu Tam**, and the teacher of the **Ra’avya** and the **Rokeach**.

**Style**: Although not one of the *Azharos*, he based his *sefer* on the list of the **Halachos Gedolos**, with many differences. It is unclear if he had a different version of Halachos Gedolos, if this was how he interpreted its vague listing, or he simply disagreed in certain instances. There are only 464 sections in the work, although the author says he grouped together similar *mitzvos*. [Toafos Re'eim attempted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118777/1739) to divide them all into 613. In each mitzvah he spells out all of his rulings related to that mitzvah. As such, it’s an often-quoted *halacha sefer*.

### Section 3 – The Rambam and those who followed him

##### 8) [Rambam](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=8933) – [Rav Moshe ben Maimon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) (c. 1135 – 1204 CE)

**Life**: Also known as **Maimonides**. He is arguably the most famous Jewish philosopher of all time, and one of the most influential Torah scholars of his time. He was born in Spain, and eventually came to live in Egypt. He was the first to structurally organize and codify all of the laws scattered throughout the Talmud into clear, delineated topics and sections. He also codified laws that aren’t presently relevant but will be when the Temple is rebuilt. This was all put in his work **Mishneh Torah**. Besides his **Sefer HaMitzvos**, he wrote a commentary on the entire Mishnah, and the philosophical work **Moreh Nevuchim**, or Guide to the Perplexed. All three of these works were originally written in Arabic, and later translated by others into Hebrew. He famously became the Sultan of Egypt’s personal doctor in his later years.

**Unique Characteristics**: He prefaces his list with 14 “*Shorashim*”, which are the rules he created and followed to determine which *mitzvos* made it into his list. If you read any verse in *Chumash* and follow his rules, you’ll apparently know if it counts as a *mitzvah* or not. Every *mitzvah* he lists, he tells you the verse it came from, a source in *Chazal* that it’s a *mitzvah* (if one exists), and where in the *gemarra* one can learn more about it. He standardized listing the *mitzvos* as a list of 248 positive *mitzvos* and 365 negative *mitzvos*<sup>13</sup>.

##### 9) [Ramban](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=8933) – [Rav Moshe ben Nachman](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F) (1194 – 1270 CE)

**Life**: Spent most of his life in Spain. Renowned Jewish scholar, mystic, and doctor. He wrote a commentary on the Torah, Talmud, Rif, and Responsa. He also wrote on many topics.

**Style**: He doesn’t explicitly write his list anywhere. Rather, he comments on the **Rambam**’s Sefer HaMitzvos and let’s you know when he disagrees. Silence often implies concurrence. After the Rambam’s list the Ramban tells you the 25 mitzvos that he feels the Rambam “forgot”. However, this list isn’t enough, as reading the whole *sefer* yields a much greater disagreement between these two giants<sup>14</sup>. At the very end of his commentary the Ramban summarizes every mitzvah he disagrees with, and it’s up to you to figure out how he fills in the gaps.

##### 10) [Sefer HaChinuch](https://hebrewbooks.org/40631) (identity disputed)

**Life**: Many<sup>15</sup> assume this work was written by [**Rav Aharon HaLevi**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%90%22%D7%94) of Barcelona (1235 – c. 1290 CE). However, this assumption has been disproven, as the author frequently disagrees explicitly with known rulings of Rav Aharon HaLevi. A convincing argument has been made<sup>16</sup> that the author is really Rav Aharon’s brother, **Rav Pinchas HaLevi**. Either way, we know for a fact the author was a Levi from Barcelona. He seemingly was a student of the **Rashba**, as he frequently agrees with the latter’s rulings.

**Style**: His list is exclusively based on the list of the **Rambam**<sup>17</sup>. However, he reordered the list according to the weekly *parsha*. He writes that this way his son (for whom he wrote the book) will know what mitzvos appear in each *parsha*. Each *mitzvah* is listed with a title, the verse, a general description of the *mitzvah*, the “*shoresh*” of the *mitzvah* (see next section), a summary of its relevant *halachos*, and details of its obligation.

**Unique Characteristics**: What makes Sefer HaChinuch so unique and enjoyed by many is that he shares what he believes is the reason behind each *mitzvah*, which he calls the “*shoresh*” of the *mitzvah*. He also at the end of each *mitzvah* tells you who is obligated in it, when, and where. He also lists the punishment for neglecting the *mitzvah*.

##### 11) [Semag – Sefer Mitzvos Gadol](https://hebrewbooks.org/20520) - [Rav Moshe of Kotzi](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99) (13th century)

**Life**: He was one of the Ba’alei HaTosafos and was born in France. He was a student of **Rabbi Yehudah HaChossid**. He writes in the introduction to the work that he consistently received visions in his dreams commanding him to write a two-volume work on the *Taryag Mitzvos*. He eventually complied.

**Style**: His *sefer* is a work of *halacha*. He goes through each *mitzvah* and lists all the halachos related to that mitzvah. Very often he quotes the language of the *gemarra* and the **Rambam**, although as one of the Ba’alei HaTosafos he also brings the rulings of the Ashkenazi *Rishonim*. At the beginning of the work he lists all the *Taryag Mitzvos*, basically making an index for the rest of the work. His list is mostly based on the **Rambam**’s, differing only in 20 *mitzvos*.

##### 12) [Zohar HaRakiah](https://hebrewbooks.org/30766) – [Rav Shimon ben Tzemach](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%97_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9F) (1361 – 1444 CE)

**Life**: He lived in Algeria. Besides being a major halachic decisor, he was a mathematician, philosopher, and doctor.

**Style**: He wrote his work as a “commentary” to **Rav Shlomo ibn Gabirol**’s *Azharos* (see above). However, it’s not really a commentary, but merely uses the latter’s listing as a springboard to discuss his own listing of the *mitzvos*. He mostly follows the **Rambam** and **Ramban**, so he rejects most of what Rashbag counts.

**Unique Characteristics**: Being one of the later *Rishonim*, he had access to all of the works that came before him. He uses every opportunity he can to bring the disputes of the Rambam and the Ramban, and to discuss the logic and merits of each. He will often take sides, or come up with his own opinion. In this work he was the first to suggest that when the Rambam says *derashos* are *MiDerabanan*, he meant they’re Biblical but were extracted by the Rabbis.

##### 13) [Sefer Charedim](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=143568&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=0) – [Rav Elazar Azikri](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99) (1533 – 1600 CE)

**Life**: He was born and lived in Tzfas. He was a contemporary of **Rav Yosef Caro**, the **Arizal** and **Rav Shlomo Alkabetz**. He was the author of the popular *shabbos* *zemer* *Yedid Nefesh*<sup>18</sup>.

**Style**: He only writes *mitzvos* that apply today yet includes *mitzvos* *MiDivrei Kabbalah* and *MiDivrei Soferim*. To be honest, I don't think his list reaches 613, but I haven't confirmed that yet.

**Unique Characteristics**: He divided the *mitzvos* into the body parts, so one can always know which *mitzvos* can be fulfilled with which part of the body. Being one of the last to count the *mitzvos*, he had the knowledge of all the opinions which preceded him. He lists all the *mitzvos* which everyone or most agree to in a general way, and will list lone opinions by name.

---

This isn't an exhaustive list, but I believe these are the main ones. See **Chida**'s [**Shem HaGedolim** II § אזהרות](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30595&st=&pgnum=3) where he lists more *azharos* which I've never heard of. I left out **Ibn Ezra**'s [**Yesod Morah**](https://hebrewbooks.org/32671), **Rabbeinu Yonah**'s [**Sha'arei Teshuva**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52052&st=&pgnum=131), [**Semak**](https://hebrewbooks.org/22270), and the **Chofetz Chaim**'s [**Sefer HaMitzvos HaKatzar**](https://hebrewbooks.org/33950), as they don't list all 613. I left out [**Ma'amar HaSeichel**](https://hebrewbooks.org/7157), attributed to [**Ra'avan**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F), since if I'm not mistaken it just reorders the Semag's list into the Ten Commandments. I left out [**Mitzvos Hashem**](https://hebrewbooks.org/22355), as it's basically just a compilation of the Rambam, Ramban, Semag, Semak, and Chareidim.

---

<sup>1</sup> Including **Rav Sherirah Gaon** (**Zichron LaRishonim** p. 191), **Meiri** in **Beis HaBechira** *Pesicha L’Maseches Avos*, **Ra’avad** in his **Sefer HaKabbalah**, **Rambam** in **Pe’er HaDor** § 229 (also printed in **Iggeros HaRambam** *Chidushei HaRambam* § 191), **Ramban** in his introduction to **Rambam**’s **Sefer HaMitzvos**, (it’s also almost explicit in the **Rambam**’s statement in ***ibid*** *Shorashim* § 10), **Tosafos Rid** to **Megillah** 30b *s.v.* ושאר כל ימות, and **Zohar HaRakiah** *Introduction*, *Aseh* § 11, 50 (see below). Later authorities who say this are the **Aruch LaNer** in his **Teshuvos Binyan Tzion** § 134 and **Netziv** in his **Ha’emek She’eilah** 1:25, 9:2, 16:6, 45:4, 100:23, and 128:7.

<sup>2</sup> **Rashi** to **Sukkah** 38b *s.v.* הוא אומר ברוך, **Tosafos HaRosh** *ad. loc. s.v.* שמע ולא ענה, **Tosafos** to **Gittin** 88b *s.v.* ובעובדי כוכבים, **Sefer Yereim** *End*, **Semag** *Hakdama*. See also **Mesoras HaShas** to **Bava Kamma** 53b, **Rashi** *s.v.* ה"ג מאי ניהו.

<sup>3</sup> See further in **Yad Malachi** *Klalei Bahag* § 4, **Shem HaGedolim** II § הלכות גדולות, Introduction to **Halachos Gedolos** (5635 Warsaw ed. and Rav Hildesheimer ed.), and **Maharatz Chayes** to **Sukkah** *ad. loc.*

<sup>4</sup> To **Exodus** 24:12.

<sup>5</sup> For the reason for these two, see **Rav Yerucham Fischel Perla**’s commentary to *Lo Sa’aseh* § 141, 142.

<sup>6</sup> For the reason for these latter two, see **Rav Yerucham Fischel Perla**’s commentary to *Aseh* § 1.

<sup>7</sup> **Chida** in **Shem HaGedolim** I § רבנו האי גאון.

<sup>8</sup> **Rav Wolf Heidenheim** in his **Machzor L’Shavuos**, concluding like the **Teshuvos Maharshal** § 29.

<sup>9</sup> **Rav Yitzchak Isaac ben Yaakov** (19th century) in **Otzar HaSefarim** § אזהרות says it was written before **Rav Sa’adiah Gaon**, or at least in the same lifetime. See also **Rav Naftali Tzvi Hildesheimer**’s introduction to **Halachos Gedolos**, who brings those who date this *piyut* to the time of the **Halachos Gedolos**.

<sup>10</sup> For example: **Tosafos** to **Yoma** 8a *s.v.* דכולי עלמא, **Sukkah** 49a *s.v.* שכל מזבח, **Bava Basra** 145b *s.v.* ואין השביעית, **Makkos** 3b *s.v.* איכא דאמרי, and **Niddah** 30a *s.v.* ושמע מינה. **Piskei Rosh** *Makkos* 1:3 also cites it.

<sup>11</sup> See **HaTorah HaGoelet** IV p. 156 by **Rav Tzvi Yehudah Kook**.

<sup>12</sup> See **Keser Shem Tov** p. 446, by **Rav Shev Tov Gaguine** (20th century).

<sup>13</sup> Although he was preceded by the *Azharos* of **Rav Shlomo ibn Gabirol**, the latter didn’t make it a list of *mitzvos*. He just divided his piyut this way.

<sup>14</sup> See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96596/1739) for more on their dispute.

<sup>15</sup> For example: **Shach** to **Shulchan Aruch** *Yoreh Deah* 87:1 § 1, **Sidrei Tahara** *ad.loc.* 196:4 § 18, **Pischei Teshuvah** *ad. loc.* *Choshen Mishpat* 1:1 § 2, **Nodah B’Yehudah** II *Yoreh Deah* § 53, **Teshuvos Chasam Sofer** *Orach Chaim* § 32, **Aruch HaShulchan** *Orach Chaim* 1:14, *Yoreh Deah* 270:6.

<sup>16</sup> **Professor Yisroel Ta-Shma**, **Kiryat Sefer** XV p. 789-791.

<sup>17</sup> However, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84185/1739), which discusses why the **Chinuch** differs from the **Rambam** in exactly one *mitzvah*.

<sup>18</sup> However, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_ben_Moshe_Azikri#cite_note-3).

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. Two notes: I'm pretty sure Rambam wrote Mishneh Torah in Hebrew. Also, the Mosad Harav Kook edition of Kitvei HaRamban has a work deriving the 613 Mitzvos from the Ten Commandments. I saw someone say it is not actually the Ramban, but I didn't research it myself.

Comment: @N.T. if you reread it carefully, he says that the three works in Arabic were Sefer Hamitzvot, Perush Hamishnah, and Moreh Nevuchim.

Comment: @N.T. yes I've seen that work, but I don't think he lists all 613 in it. Maybe I'll add it this info to his paragraph...

Comment: IINM, the mitzvot list in Halachot Gedolot is independent of the body of the work, and of different authorship.

Comment: If you're sticking with lists of 613: most of the azharot don't list 613. For example, Atah Hinchalta has ~570.

Comment: @magicker72 my impression is the azharos were specifically intending on listing all the *mitzvos*. Perhaps I'm mistaken, but those who try to figure out the 613 in the *azharos* (rav yerucham fischel perla, nesiv mitzvosecha, yashir moshe , rav refoel shapira, etc.) seem to assume like me.

Comment: @robev The above-mentioned machzor writes in general about azharot: נראה ודאי שאיש מן הפייטנים לא התייחס אל מניין המצוות כאל עניין מכריע, מחייב וחמור, and about אתה הנחלת that ברור שאין הפייטן רוצה להשלים את מלאכת מניין המצוות כי בולט הוא שלא כל המצוות נימנו, with examples of אכילת מרור and אכילת חדש and נתינת מחצית השקל and פרו ורבו and מכה ומקלל אביו ואמו and לא תתגודדו and ...

Comment: @magicker72 we can debate this all we want but I'm not sure that proves anything. Rav saadiah gaon left out 200 mitzvos from what the Rambam counts and replaces them with ones the Rambam never would have counted. I gave some examples above, mitzvos which any Jew would have thought should be included. I'm not saying I'm right but I think it's the proper default assumption and perhaps the view of your machzor isn't undisputed.

Comment: In any event 3 of the 5 azharos I'm aware of and listed have been divided into 613 mitzvos. I admit I think I recall seeing that atah hinchalta and Rav Eliyahu hazaken are either very difficult to count or they are clearly lacking some mitzvos. Still, they count a lot closer to 613 than the semak or chofetz chaim.

Comment: Regarding the last few comments, a list that does not contain 613 mitzvot is not necessarily incomplete; the author may not have felt bound to the count of 613. See, e.g. [this explanation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59977/only-613-commandments-cant-be/95024#95024). cc @magicker72

Comment: @Alex Absolutely. I was only pointing it out because the answer explicitly excluded other lists because they didn't hit 613, and it seemed inconsistent to me.

Comment: Rambam: והוא במה שמונין מנין המצות הנה נשתבשו בו רבים בענינם לא אוכל ספר גודל גנותם...נמשכו כלם אחר דברי בעל הלכות גדולות ולא נטו מכוונתו במספרם כי אם נטיה קטנה...וכן כל מה ששמעתי האזהרות רבות המספר המחוברות אצלנו בארץ ספרד

Comment: See also Shem HaGedolim on Azharot in the section on Seforim.

Comment: @N.T. Thanks. Added.